# Monodevelop & Xamarin Studio addin project paths & templates

Tags: xamarin, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm writing an addin for Monodevelop and Xamarin Studio, and it's working, but I have had to hard encode some settings.

What objects do I query to get:

- Templates available in the IDE.
- Path to currently selected output (../bin/Debug).
- Output executable filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Path to currently selected output (../bin/Debug).

If you mean the active project configuration (if one is active...), you can get the currently selected configuration id in the IDE via:

```
IBuildTarget buildTarget = MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.ProjectOperations.CurrentSelectedBuildTarget;
```

Assuming that your `buildTarget` is a `DotNetProject`, you can get list of the project's configurations that are available via:

```
((DotNetProject)buildTarget).Configurations
```

DotNetProject Configurations have an `OutputDirectory` property that return a `FilePath` object.

> Output executable filename.

Once you have the configuration that you need:

```
DotNetProjectConfiguration.CompiledOutputName
```

> Templates available in the IDE.

Templates are provided via the "/MonoDevelop/Ide/ProjectTemplates" Addin extension and there are solution, project, file templates, etc.. If you really need to enumerate all of them, look in

```
[src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates/][1]
```